# How to use a GUID returned from an Android Web Service Method

Tags: android, session, soap, guid

I am hoping to get an answer to an issue I am having. I have 2 web service methods. The first is a login webmethod which returns a SessionID and the second is a getExpenseTypes which should return an array of expenses but instead tells me that the SessionID is invalid.

My Login Request

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(new URI(urlset.getUrl()));

                post.setHeader("SOAPAction", urlset.getAction());
                post.setHeader("Content-Type", urlset.getContentType());

                post.setEntity(new StringEntity(login.getSoapLogin(args[0].trim(),
                        args[1].trim())));


                HttpClient client = customHttpClient.getNewHttpClient();

                HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
                statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                if (entity != null) {

                    instream = entity.getContent();
                    result = stringManipulator.convertStreamToString(instream);
                    sessionID = parseSessionId.parseSessionId(result);
                    instream.close();

                }
```

And it returns

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><LoginResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><LoginResult>8e576dc05aa74c699640bb12094e0bde</LoginResult></LoginResponse></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

I assumed that `8e576dc05aa74c699640bb12094e0bde` was the SessionID but later I found out that this is a GUID.

So the second webmethod

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(new URI(urlset.getUrl()));
                post.setHeader("SOAPAction", "http://tempuri.org/IMobileService/GetExpenseTypes");
                post.setHeader("Content-Type", urlset.getContentType());
                Log.e("args[0]", args[0]);
                String sentity = getExpenseType.getExpenseTypeTest(args[0]
                        .trim());

                post.setEntity(new StringEntity(sentity));


                CustomHttpClient customHttpClient = new CustomHttpClient();
                HttpClient client = customHttpClient.getNewHttpClient();

                HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
                statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

                if (entity != null) {

                    instream = entity.getContent();
                    result = stringManipulator.convertStreamToString(instream);
                    instream.close();

                }
```

Where the stored session id is concatenated into a StringEntity like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:GetExpenseTypes>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:sessionID>2b89eff0ebcf4fb8a11636256d94553e</tem:sessionID>
      </tem:GetExpenseTypes>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

and it returns:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><GetExpenseTypesResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><GetExpenseTypesResult>ERR: Session 00000000000000000000000000000000 won't be found.</GetExpenseTypesResult></GetExpenseTypesResponse></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

Though I was expecting:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <GetExpenseTypesResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
         <GetExpenseTypesResult>[{"Id":3,"ExpenseTypeName":"Accomodation","CustomerId":null},{"Id":4,"ExpenseTypeName":"Communication","CustomerId":null},{"Id":12,"ExpenseTypeName":"Entertainment","CustomerId":2},{"Id":1,"ExpenseTypeName":"Flight","CustomerId":null},{"Id":10,"ExpenseTypeName":"Fuel","CustomerId":2},{"Id":11,"ExpenseTypeName":"Meals","CustomerId":2},{"Id":2,"ExpenseTypeName":"Mileage","CustomerId":2},{"Id":13,"ExpenseTypeName":"Office Supplies","CustomerId":2},{"Id":6,"ExpenseTypeName":"Subsistence","CustomerId":null},{"Id":5,"ExpenseTypeName":"Transport","CustomerId":null}]</GetExpenseTypesResult>
      </GetExpenseTypesResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

So, I have been told that it is because the SessionID is sent as a GUID but I have never used these before. I just plugged in what looked like a string as the session id. This is clearly wrong. How do I handle receiving the GUID instead of a session id?

Thanks.

Comment: You can store that GUID in String variable. What is exactly your problem?

Comment: is the GUID: 8e576dc05aa74c699640bb12094e0bde? I am storing it in a String variable which I send like: <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:GetExpenseTypes>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:sessionID>2b89eff0ebcf4fb8a11636256d94553e</tem:sessionID>
      </tem:GetExpenseTypes>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope> but I get an error saying that the Session: 0000000000000000 does not exist. So I am thinking that plugging it straight in does not work.

Comment: 32bits, yeah seems to be GUID.

Comment: So does that mean I cannot just paste in the returned <SessionID> into the next request? If so, how do I include the session id? I get correct values returned using Soap UI

Comment: You can just pass it as a String to next request. First store it into some string variable then pass it.\

Comment: Ok, this is probably a stupid question but I store 2b89eff0ebcf4fb8a11636256d94553e in a string variable called SessionID and then I concatenate with the soap request like: <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"; xmlns:tem="tempuri.org/">; <soapenv:Header/> <soapenv:Body> <tem:GetExpenseTypes> <!--Optional:--> <tem:sessionID>2b89eff0ebcf4fb8a11636256d94553e</tem:sessionID> </tem:GetExpenseTypes> </soapenv:Body> </soapenv:Envelope>. So this must be wrong... because just doing that returns..

Comment: <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><GetExpenseTypesResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><GetExpenseTypesResult>ERR: Session 00000000000000000000000000000000 won't be found.</GetExpenseTypesResult></GetExpenseTypesResponse></s:Body></s:Envelope>